# Xcode 8 : UI Testing Remote Button Error: Failed to find focused element

Tags: xcode, xcode8, tvos, xcode-ui-testing

I was trying to capture ui elements using recording mode in XCUI testing using xcode 8 but it throws error:

> Xcode UI Testing Remote Button Error: Failed to find focused element.

But if I use remote method(e.g: 
`XCUIRemote.shared().press(.select)` 
) in my code then it works fine. 
Only issue is in recording mode all the remote functionalities seems to be broken.

BTW my code is working fine on Xcode 7, is this a known issue on Xcode 8 ?

Comment: Please show your code and describe what are the expected results and what you get instead.

Answer (score 0):

Recording mode on xcode 8 seems to be quite buggy(unlike the automation trace on xcode 7) and unable to actually generate the correct element command , I would recommend using the method that works correctly for you.